# i18n dont find the translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I18n cant find the translation even if the translation is present in my YML,

```
translation missing: fr.activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.email.not_found

errors:
    messages:
      already_confirmed: a déjà été confirmé(e)
      confirmation_period_expired: doit être confirmé(e) en %{period}, veuillez en demander un(e) autre
      expired: est expiré, veuillez en demander un autre
      not_found: n’a pas été trouvé(e)
      not_locked: n’était pas verrouillé(e)
      not_saved:
        one: 'une erreur a empêché ce (cet ou cette) %{resource} d’être enregistré(e) :'
        other: "%{count} erreurs ont empêché ce (cet ou cette) %{resource} d’être enregistré(e) :"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must follows correctly the "pattern", the locale is the root, in this case `fr`:

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              not_found: Email not found
```